# Is there any inequality solver in sympy for python?

Tags: python, solver, inequality

I have the following inequality :

$$ (1-\frac{9}{10}\omega)^2 \geq (1-\omega)^2$$

which is $\omega = \frac{20}{19}$

is there any SymPy code in python to implement it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack. Please format your equations so it is readable.

Comment: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/inequalities.html. Refer to this documentation for python sympy inequality solvers